# Problem in running GCP code, it does not find the table and therefore does not let run

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a problem with `GCP` code, I do not know if it is something related to syntax or tables that I may not have opened correctly.
I upload the code here, and also a picture where you can see what tables I have. I would be very happy to help

```
SELECT
  url,
  COUNT(1) AS count_mentions
FROM
  `vernal-parser-311415.isreal_media.israel_media_person`
WHERE
  LOWER(person) LIKE '%netanyahu%'
GROUP BY
  url
ORDER BY
  count_mentions DESC
LIMIT
  10;
```

Comment: Please provide more details about your use case and GCP products you're using.